# gsutil acl set command AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden

Tags: google-cloud-storage

I am following the steps of setting up Django on Google App Engine, and since Gunicorn does not serve static files, I have to store my static files to Google Cloud Storage.

I am at the line with "Create a Cloud Storage bucket and make it publically readable." on https://cloud.google.com/python/django/flexible-environment#run_the_app_on_your_local_computer. I ran the following commands as suggested:

```
$ gsutil mb gs://your-gcs-bucket
$ gsutil defacl set public-read gs://your-gcs-bucket
```

The first command is supposed to create a new storage bucket, and the second line sets its default ACL. When I type in the command, the second line returns an error.

```
Setting default object ACL on gs://your-gcs-bucket/...
AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden
```

I also tried other commands setting or getting acl, but all returns the same error, with no additional information.

I am a newbie with google cloud services, could anyone point out what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out myself, and it is kind of silly. I didn't notice if the first command is successful or not. And apparently it did not.

For a newbie like me, it is important to note that things like **bucket name and project name are global** across its space. And what happened was that the name I used to create a new bucket is already used by other people. And no wonder that I do not have permission to access that bucket.

A better way to work with this is to name the bucket name wisely, like prefixing project name and application name.